# Clarifying the "why" behind SVD, LU, QR and Woodbury matrix identity decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I've been reading about matrix decompositions for a while now, but I always somehow seem to forget the reasons why they exist, and this irritates me when I see them applied in various branches of mathematics. Matrix decompositions I most often bump into are the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), [LU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), [QR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) and the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

In this post, I would like to find out the intuition and **why** these decompositions exist, because understanding the **why**, is what illustrates to me the relevance and context of those decompositions, which helps me remember them better. In many source, these decompositions are simply stated, which I think, is analogous to writing uncommented C code. Sure you can write them down in one line and the assembler will compile them no problem, but it would be nice to see the motivation behind the authors writing this code.

**My question thus is:** How would one summarize each of these decompositions in couple of sentences, why were they derived? For what reason and application?

Comment: I believe a comparison to design patterns would be more accurate than one to uncommented code (not mutually exclusive). Also, I am not sure Woodbury belongs here. In any case, why aren't Wikipedia articles not sufficient to answer these questions separately?

Comment: The point of some of these decompositions is to simplify another problem. For example, SVD can provide a useful basis for some least squares fitting methods.

Answer (score 1):

For the LU decomposition it helps determining for example the determinant of a matrix or its rank . Because the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal elements . Or calculating the inverse of a matrix (this method is used in programs).

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your help. If you can fill me in also on the remaining three I can possibly accept your answer :)